# Want to disable flash caching?

Tags: asp.net

I have a .swf flash gallery that loads pics from a XML file

the probelm is when I modify the XML the modifications do not reflect on the flash till I delete the browsing cache from the browser

I tried to disable caching using code like this

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.AddHeader("Pragma","no-cache");
Response.Expires = -1;
```

but not working

is there any workaround for this ?

thanks

Comment: that should be enough, I recommend you to check your cache headers using fiddler and post what you find

Answer (score 1):

You could add a parameter to you XML file request. Something like "pictures.xml?dummy=[timestamp]". In that case, your browser thinks you are requesting a new file.

Hope this will help. :)